# How to read node in xml with condition

Tags: c#, xml

This is my XML file

```
<problem>
    <sct:fsn>Myocardial infarction (disorder)</sct:fsn>
    <sct:code>22298006</sct:code>
    <sct:description>Heart attack</sct:description>
    <sct:description>Infarction of heart</sct:description>
    <sct:description>MI - Myocardial infarction</sct:description>
    <sct:description>Myocardial infarct</sct:description>
    <sct:description>Cardiac infarction</sct:description>
    <sct:description>Myocardial infarction</sct:description>
</problem>
```

how to select Code and fsn ? if i have description.
please help  thanks

Comment: Where is the `xml` file??

Comment: @ArghyaC: It was there. But not in the code block thus cannot see. I have formatted the post. Hope to see it soon

Comment: The description you have is the concatenation of all `<sct:description>` nodes?

Comment: You should also post if any efforts you have made for the same!

Answer (score 0):

You missed a important part: the namespace declaration.

In your original XML file, you probably have one or more attributes like `xmlns:xxx`. These attributes have a special meaning, as the allow to use two different XML *vocabularies* in the same file.

To find those elements with namespaces (notice the `xxx:` part; in your case, it is `sct:`), you'll need to use the `XmlNamespaceManager` class, like in the sample below.

Be warned: the attribute value ("example" in this case) must be the same used into the `AddNamespace` method, verbatim.

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(@"
        <problem xmlns:sct='example'>
            <sct:fsn>Myocardial infarction (disorder)</sct:fsn>
            <sct:code>22298006</sct:code>
            <sct:description>Heart attack</sct:description>
            <sct:description>Infarction of heart</sct:description>
            <sct:description>MI - Myocardial infarction</sct:description>
            <sct:description>Myocardial infarct</sct:description>
            <sct:description>Cardiac infarction</sct:description>
            <sct:description>Myocardial infarction</sct:description>
        </problem>");

var xmlns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
    xmlns.AddNamespace("sct", "example");
   // same as     xmlns:sct=  'example'

// This is important: ---------------------------------V
Console.WriteLine(xml.SelectSingleNode("//sct:code", xmlns).InnerText);
```